# Add hyperlink dynamically to a some text of text field

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink

I want to add hyperlink for entered text in a text field, i searched in so many ways but all are saying we cant insert html tags in the text field because the  text field takes only text as a value. But my requirement is to add hyperlink to some text only which is selected by the user from all entered text, and when i will do edit it must show as a hyperlink.

I want to show like whenever we are sending any mail if we want to send some text as a hyperlink, we will right click the text and add hyperlink, In the same way if a user enters some text, during entering he wants to add hyperlink for some text, after submitting the text if user do edit the hyperlink text must be visible in hyperlink mode only.

Is there any way or any component to show hyperlink whenever user selects particular text?

Please help on this.

Thanks,

Ratna.

Comment: Please specify the code here on which u are working and want this functionality to be implement that will clear the ques

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with a standard `textarea`. You may want to look at an option like [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com), but that may be overkill for your purposes.

If I've misinterpreted what you're attempting to do, please update your post with some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You need some javascript library to make that input dinamic and give the options you want to the user, i recomend you [markItUp!](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/) because is simple and compatible with jQuery who make it more simple.

That's what i understand with your question, by default you can't do it.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to add this markItUp to existing text field?   I added like this $('#title').markItUp(mySettings); but not working?